Failed to create Discovery Client @EnableDiscoveryClient and using eureka client starter dependency getting error
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:55772,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\OptivalueTek\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2024.1\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\SpringBoot Projects\Client\target\classes;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client\4.1.3\spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-starter\4.1.4\spring-cloud-starter-4.1.4.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-context\4.1.4\spring-cloud-context-4.1.4.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\6.2.6\spring-security-crypto-6.2.6.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-commons\4.1.4\spring-cloud-commons-4.1.4.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-rsa\1.1.3\spring-security-rsa-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk18on\1.78\bcprov-jdk18on-1.78.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client\4.1.3\spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\client5\httpclient5\5.2.3\httpclient5-5.2.3.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\core5\httpcore5\5.2.5\httpcore5-5.2.5.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\core5\httpcore5-h2\5.2.5\httpcore5-h2-5.2.5.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\netflix\eureka\eureka-client\2.0.3\eureka-client-2.0.3.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.20\xstream-1.4.20.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\io\github\x-stream\mxparser\1.2.2\mxparser-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.1\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\jakarta\ws\rs\jakarta.ws.rs-api\3.1.0\jakarta.ws.rs-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.1\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\netflix\spectator\spectator-api\1.7.3\spectator-api-1.7.3.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.16\slf4j-api-2.0.16.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.3\httpclient-4.5.3.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.16\httpcore-4.4.16.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.16.1\commons-codec-1.16.1.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.10\commons-configuration-1.10.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.15.4\jackson-annotations-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.15.4\jackson-core-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.15.4\jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\netflix\netflix-commons\netflix-eventbus\0.3.0\netflix-eventbus-0.3.0.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\netflix\netflix-commons\netflix-infix\0.3.0\netflix-infix-0.3.0.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\commons-jxpath\commons-jxpath\1.3\commons-jxpath-1.3.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.3\joda-time-2.3.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr-runtime\3.4\antlr-runtime-3.4.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\antlr\stringtemplate\3.2.1\stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.10.1\gson-2.10.1.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\netflix\servo\servo-core\0.5.3\servo-core-0.5.3.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math\2.2\commons-math-2.2.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.5.4\jettison-1.5.4.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\netflix\eureka\eureka-core\2.0.3\eureka-core-2.0.3.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\woodstox\woodstox-core\6.2.1\woodstox-core-6.2.1.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\4.2.1\stax2-api-4.2.1.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\33.0.0-jre\guava-33.0.0-jre.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.2\failureaccess-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\listenablefuture\9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.41.0\checker-qual-3.41.0.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.23.0\error_prone_annotations-2.23.0.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\2.8\j2objc-annotations-2.8.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer\4.1.4\spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer-4.1.4.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-loadbalancer\4.1.4\spring-cloud-loadbalancer-4.1.4.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\reactor-core\3.6.9\reactor-core-3.6.9.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.4\reactive-streams-1.0.4.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\addons\reactor-extra\3.5.2\reactor-extra-3.5.2.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-cache\3.2.9\spring-boot-starter-cache-3.2.9.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\6.1.12\spring-context-support-6.1.12.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.1.12\spring-beans-6.1.12.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\com\stoyanr\evictor\1.0.0\evictor-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.2.9\spring-boot-starter-3.2.9.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.2.9\spring-boot-3.2.9.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.1.12\spring-context-6.1.12.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.1.12\spring-aop-6.1.12.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.1.12\spring-expression-6.1.12.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.12.9\micrometer-observation-1.12.9.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.12.9\micrometer-commons-1.12.9.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.2.9\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.9.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.2.9\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.2.9.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.14\logback-classic-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.14\logback-core-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.21.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.21.1\log4j-api-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.16\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.16.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\2.2\snakeyaml-2.2.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.1.12\spring-core-6.1.12.jar;C:\Users\OptivalueTek\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.1.12\spring-jcl-6.1.12.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.selfOrganization.ClientApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55772', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.9)

2024-09-07T22:48:47.253+05:30  INFO 16760 --- [client] [           main] com.selfOrganization.ClientApplication   : Starting ClientApplication using Java 17.0.11 with PID 16760 (D:\SpringBoot Projects\Client\target\classes started by OptivalueTek in D:\SpringBoot Projects\Client)
2024-09-07T22:48:47.255+05:30  INFO 16760 --- [client] [           main] com.selfOrganization.ClientApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-09-07T22:48:48.156+05:30  INFO 16760 --- [client] [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=08057301-6bec-31f9-af26-15314f0f9ad3
2024-09-07T22:48:49.025+05:30  WARN 16760 --- [client] [           main] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger : Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. While this cache implementation is useful for development and tests, it's recommended to use Caffeine cache in production.You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath.
2024-09-07T22:48:49.076+05:30  INFO 16760 --- [client] [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2024-09-07T22:48:49.081+05:30 ERROR 16760 --- [client] [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaRegistration           : error getting CloudEurekaClient

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eurekaClient' parameter 3: No qualifying bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.TransportClientFactories<?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:376) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:375) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:373) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:128) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:116) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281) ~[spring-core-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:482) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getEurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:469) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:257) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:202) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:990) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:628) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at com.selfOrganization.ClientApplication.main(ClientApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.TransportClientFactories<?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1880) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2024-09-07T22:48:49.092+05:30  WARN 16760 --- [client] [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'
2024-09-07T22:48:49.104+05:30  INFO 16760 --- [client] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-09-07T22:48:49.140+05:30 ERROR 16760 --- [client] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:288) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:469) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:257) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:202) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:990) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:628) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at com.selfOrganization.ClientApplication.main(ClientApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient()" is null
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 12 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55772', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.selfOrganization</groupId>
    <artifactId>Client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Eureka Server</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

application.yml:
spring:
  application:
    name: client

server:
  port: 8081

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client :
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry : true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone : http://localhost:8761/eureka/

I'm not able to create discovery client.

Looks like you are using Spring Boot and Spring Cloud dependencies but haven't included the specific Eureka client dependencies. In order to fix the TransportClientFactories issue, you'll need to ensure you have the correct Spring Cloud and Eureka dependencies.
updated pom.xml,
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Cloud Eureka Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

